# Core access in system using extension interface pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, plugins, interface

Regarding the Extension Interface Design Pattern below, how can I make the client/core binary acessible to the extensions developer? I thought of dependency injection of a core facade object. But I'm not sure if this is reasonable design (context is cpp so binary compatibility may play a role). What is the common practice of the API design?

[image]

Comment: Binary compatibility is always going to be a problem with statically compiled languages. It can be alleviated by making sure that you don't make an ABI-breaking update of your build toolchain, and when you do such an update you need to be very specific about it in your documentation. Having [semantic versioning](http://semver.org) helps, but explicit documentation is mandatory.

Comment: As for your patterns, a common way (I think) is to have two interface classes: On extension interface class, which the extensions factory function returns a pointer to. And then a "system" interface class, and the program passes a pointer to it to the extensions factory function.